# Function the separates even and odd numbers using linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying, to get a number from a user and create 2 linked lists, one with only even numbers, the other one with odd numbers, I have to return the number of total numbers have been inserted, and pass by reference the linked-lists.
my main issue is with the return of the 2 new linked lists, here is what I have done so far. I get an error
Error   C2440   'function': cannot convert from 'node **' to 'node'.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct node{
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    }node;

    struct node* head;
    int get_values(node,node);

    void main() {
        node *even_node,*odd_node;
        get_values(&even_node,&odd_node);

    }
    int get_values(node *even, node *odd) {
        int value, counter_total = 0;
        node  *curr_even;
        node  *curr_odd;
        head = NULL;
        printf("enter value:");
        scanf_s("%d", &value);
        if (value == -1) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            even = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            curr_even = even;
            even->data = value;
            counter_total++;
        }
        else {
            odd = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            curr_odd = odd;
            odd->data = value;
            counter_total++;
        }
        //2nd and on insertion.
        while (value != -1) {
            printf("enter a value positive value");
            scanf_s("%d", &value);
            if (value == -1) {
                curr_even->next = NULL;
                curr_odd->next = NULL;
                break;
            }

            else if (value % 2 == 0) {
                curr_even->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                curr_even = curr_even->next;
                curr_even->data = value;//current value
                counter_total++;
            }
            else {
                curr_odd->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                curr_odd = curr_odd->next;
                curr_odd->data = value; //current value
                counter_total++;
            }

            return counter_total;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `even_node` is a pointer, `get_values` accepts pointers, but you are passing the *addresses* of two pointers.

Comment: Ok, so I should omit the pointer dereferencing. but still lit does not work.

Comment: Consider the other way around. You have to change the *values* of those pointers, right? So maybe the signature of the function has to be changed.

Comment: What is the purpose of code before the ```//2nd and on insertion.``` ? Could you comment your code? See [How to ask   questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code.

1. The function definition for `getvalues` should have a double pointer.
2. In the function, you are `malloc` ing at the function parameters. While you need to malloc a local variable and add it to the list.
3. You are adding an unnecessary code duplication when a single do while loop is sufficient.

See the fixed code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

struct node* head;
int get_values(node **,node **);

void main() {
    node *even_node= NULL,*odd_node= NULL;
    get_values(&even_node,&odd_node);

}
int get_values(node **even, node **odd) {
    int value, counter_total = 0;
    node  *curr_even;
    node  *curr_odd;
node  *new_node;

do
{
  printf("enter value:");
  scanf("%d", &value);
  if (value == -1) {
      return counter_total;
  }
  if (value % 2 == 0) 
  {
      new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
      new_node -> data = value;
      new_node -> next = NULL;
      if (*even == NULL)
      {
        *even = new_node;
        curr_even = *even;        
      }
      else
      {
         curr_even ->next = new_node;
         curr_even = curr_even -> next;
      }
      counter_total++;
  }
  else 
  {
      new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
      new_node -> data = value;
      new_node -> next = NULL;

      if (*even == NULL)
      {
        *even = new_node;
        curr_even = *even;        
      }
      else
      {
        curr_even ->next = new_node;
        curr_even = curr_even -> next;
      }
      counter_total++;
  }
}while (1);
}
```

Comment: You have used a double pointer since you want to return both addresses of the new linked list? isn't it possible without a double pointer? since we can declare in the main 2 types of nodes object. and pass them by reference does not get why you used pointer to pointer...

Comment: The pointer in the function itself can change value. Think of the case that the pointer is initially NULL and the first element of the list is added. Then the node pointer will have a new value (other than NULL). This changed pointer needs to be taken out of the function, so we pass the pointer itself by reference. i.e. a double pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have pass by reference you can do it as below.

```
int get_values(node **even, node **odd) {
    int value, counter_total = 0;

    printf("enter value:");
    scanf_s("%d", &value);

    while (value != -1) {
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            while(*even != NULL) even= &(*even)->next; //Move the pointer till last node. 

            *even = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            (*even)->data = value;//current value
            (*even)->next = NULL;
            counter_total++;
        }
        else {
            while(*odd != NULL) odd= &(*odd)->next;
            *odd = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            (*odd)->data = value;//current value
            (*odd)->next = NULL;
            counter_total++;
        }
        printf("enter a value positive value");
        scanf_s("%d", &value);
    }

    return counter_total;
}
```